# Mac OSX Terminal cmd/script to display HDD sectors pending allocation

Tags: macos, hard-drive, command-line, disk-utility

I've been trying to find a way to get terminal to display results of a SMART status check in the terminal for a recovery drive I use.

The cmd `diskutil info` or `diskutil info -plist /` only say whether the drive is "Verified" or not.

I'm looking for a script (or a nudge in the right direction in terms of BSD cmds) that will spit out the information on sectors of the drive... Pending, Allocated, all that stuff.

Any ideas?

Comment: Using `diskutil info disk0` will display the physical volume info if you are using a logical volume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All *Disk Utility* and *diskutil* ever show is “Not Supported”, “Verified”, or “Failing”; it is a simple summary of the SMART status.

The usual command-line tool for getting detailed SMART information is *smartctl* from the [smartmontools](https://www.smartmontools.org/) suite.
*smartctl* can display the SMART values and attributes for supported drives (i.e. internal drives, SMART does not seem to be supported over the generic USB and Firefire disk protocols).
Smartmontools does not come bundled with Mac OS X, but it is available in
[MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) ([package info](https://trac.macports.org/browser/trunk/dports/sysutils/smartmontools/Portfile)),
[Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) ([package info](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/smartmontools.rb)), and
[Fink](https://www.finkproject.org/) ([package info](https://pdb.finkproject.org/pdb/package.php/smartmontools)).

The GUI application [*SMARTReporter*](https://www.corecode.io/smartreporter/) seems mostly to be a wrapper around *smartctl*.
A web search will probably turn up other GUIs.

Comment: The link to the "smartmontools" suite was exactly what I needed, thanks!